# troubleshooting session expired using libcurl

Tags: http, session, curl, cookies, libcurl

I am trying to login to a website using libcurl in c (http website, not https). The problem is that after the login if I try to reach a page in the domain I get redirected to a page claiming my session has expired and I need to relog.

I then assumed there must be a problem with the session cookie that the website uses. This is the code I use to handle the cookie. I use these settings at my very first request when I go to the login page.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
```

I then used CURLOPT_VERBOSE to get information about the session. It seems I indeed receive a cookie and send it again in subsequent requests.

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2d952576829405ce0d25689804b525ec; path=/
```

this cookie is also used in following requests like this:

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=2d952576829405ce0d25689804b525ec
```

finally when I go to cookie.txt I also see the cookie there:

```
domain  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   2d952576829405ce0d25689804b525ec
```

So to conclude my question is: how can I further troubleshoot the issue of the expired session? Most sources on the internet explain how to get the cookie to work but in this case I don't see a problem with the cookie.

EDIT: Using the general method provided by Vasiliy Faronov I discovered that two extra cookies are normally generated from a javascript response. Apparently libcurl doesn't interpret javascript and therefore does not create the cookies. After emulating the value of the cookies everything should work so I will consider this question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a Web resource that works with a Web browser, but doesn’t work with programmatic requests, the general course of action is simple.

1. Equip yourself to examine in detail the requests and responses being sent. In your case you can probably use your Web browser’s developer tools and `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`. In many cases a packet sniffer will work.
2. Make a successful interaction with the Web browser and capture the request/reponse flow.
3. Reproduce the same request/response flow programmatically. If you are making requests in exactly the same way, reproducing all the message details as far as is practical, you should usually be getting the same successful result.
4. Alter your program step by step. Remove unneeded headers and cookies one by one, replace the `User-Agent` and so on. At some point the interaction will break and you’ll know e.g. that that particular header was significant. Or it may not break at all.